# Creating a role stops roles.add from working [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When using an existing role I can add it to a member but when it is created it is considered an invalid type.

This:

```
let Role = guild.roles.create({
   data: {
      name: 'role',
      color: 'BLUE',
      permissions: 0,
    },
    reason: 'role',
  })
```

Delivers:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

This:

```
let Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'role');
```

Delivers:

```
Command sent: -role by Skuffies
Role Successfully added.
```

Code used for adding role:

```
message.mentions.members.first().roles.add(Role);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Guild#roles#create` returns a promise, it's an asynchronous function. Whenever you attempt to add the new role it doesn't exist at the time of the execution because the role creation is still under process.

**Handling The Promise Using:** *Promise#then()*

```
let Role = guild.roles.create({
   data: {
      name: 'role',
      color: 'BLUE',
      permissions: 0,
    },
    reason: 'role'
}).then(thisNewRole => {
   const member = message.mentions.members.first();
   member.roles.add(thisNewRole);
})
```

**Handling The Promise Using:** *Async/Await*

- Ensure you're inside an async function.

```
async yourFunctuon() {
   let Role = await guild.roles.create({
   data: {
      name: 'role',
      color: 'BLUE',
      permissions: 0,
    },
    reason: 'role',
  })

   const member = message.mentions.members.first();
   member.roles.add(Role);
}
```